# angular cli serving static files instead of backend

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server, angular-cli

I wonder how to mock backend to serve files using the newest angular cli. Before angular cli I've been using gulp which was serving my web application on

```
localhost:5555
```

and I added https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-mock-server which was serving file from my mock folder  on

```
localhost:8888
```

So I've added only proxy to bypass api calls to mock server:

```
localhost:5555/api/person/documents >> localhost:8888/api/person/documents
```

And was getting on every backend call coresponding file, for above

```
/mocked/api/person/documents.json
```

I ve started from adding proxy to angular cli, but how to serve files now?

```
{
   "/api": {
   "target": "http://localhost:8888/",
   "secure": false
   }
}
```